# Javascript how to use object key as an object path?

Tags: javascript

First object is a map (with 1 element only for make it simple):

```
let dataMap = {
      Feed: "data",
    };
```

I need to assign those key values to separated path:

```
Object.keys(dataMap).forEach((value) => {
  struct[value] = Object.assign({}, struct[value], {
    "State": obj.Digital[dataMap[value]].State,
  });
});

console.log(struct);
```

Now the result looks something like this:

```
struct: { 
 Feed: { 
  State: "xy"
  } 
}
```

What I would like to do, is to change the Feed key to Feed.next.
So it would look like:

```
struct: { 
     Feed: {
      next: {
       State: "xy"
       } 
      }
     }
```

Please note that struct.Feed does exist already from the beginning, so this is not created with the code above.
My question is how should I write the dataMap object to achieve the structure above?

Is it like (it is not working):

```
let dataMap = {
          Feed[next]: "data",
        };
```

Thank you,

Comment: where do i find the path?

Comment: hmm, I mean, in the first solution inside the forEach method, struct[value] is equal to struct.Feed. What I would like to get is struct[value] equal to struct.Feed.next

Comment: please add what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var struct =  {Feed:{ State: "xy"}};
```

Add "next" property:

```
struct.Feed.next = {};
```

Create a copy of State in struct.Feed.next:

```
struct.Feed.next = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(struct.Feed));
```

Delete fields:

```
delete struct.Feed.State
delete struct.Feed.next.next
```

Object now is:

```
struct {Feed: next{State: "xy"}}
```